# Numpy : difference between np.repeat and np.broadcast_to

Tags: python, numpy

1. Why is the following code returning False ? I thought that `np.broadcast_to` will increase the dimensin of the array the same way `np.repeat` does.
2. Can i reproduce the result given by `np.repeat` with `np.broadcast_to` ?

```
    import numpy as np
    n = 100
    d = 10
    A = np.random.uniform(size=(n,d))
    np.all(np.broadcast_to(A.reshape(n,1,d),(n,d-1,d))==np.repeat(A,d1).reshape(n,d-1,d))
```

3. More generaly, for a given aray `A` of shape (n,d), how can i reproduce `np.repeat(A,k).reshape((n,k,d))` with `np.broadcast_to` ?

Comment: Are you sure `np.repeat(A,d-1).reshape(n,d-1,d)` is what you are after? `repeat` replicates along last axis by default.

Comment: Yeah that's what i need. but i cant reproduce it with np.broadcast_to (which eat up less memory since it does not copy the arry, if i understood correctly). See the 3° i just added

Comment: My point is that you are replicating to d-1 elements, but reshaping keeping d elements. So, one element at each row end would be different.

Comment: Yeah that's the wanted behavior. I'm not shure i got your point ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of things going on here, and it would be easier to work with an array containing a small number of flag values to identify the issues. Here is a sample that is easy to work with:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 1, 2], [3, 4, 3, 4]]) # n = 2, d = 4
```

Let's see what [`broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) does:

```
>>> A.reshape(n, 1, d)
array([[[1, 2, 1, 2]],
       [[3, 4, 3, 4]]])
>>> arr.broadcast_to(_, (n, d - 1, d))
array([[[1, 2, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 1, 2]],
       [[3, 4, 3, 4],
        [3, 4, 3, 4],
        [3, 4, 3, 4]]])
```

You could achieve functionally similar arrays with [`tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html), [`stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) and [`concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html). The main difference would be that `broadcast_to` does *not* copy the data in the new dimension. Instead, it adjusts the stride so that the array appears to have the right size (leading to unexpected behavior if you're not careful, e.g. with writing to the buffer):

- `np.tile(arr.reshape(n, 1, d), (1, d - 1, 1))`
- `np.stack([arr] * (d - 1), axis=1)`
- `np.concatenate([arr.reshape(n, 1, d)] * (d - 1), axis=1)`

Now let's take a look at [`repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
>>> np.repeat(arr, d - 1)
array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4])
```

This is the flattened array, each element of which is repeated `d - 1` times. Clearly the reshape here is not going to be the same as the broadcasted/tiled version:

```
>>> _.reshape(n, d - 1, d)
array([[[1, 1, 1, 2],
        [2, 2, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 2, 2]],
       [[3, 3, 3, 4],
        [4, 4, 3, 3],
        [3, 4, 4, 4]]])
```

Clearly, the element-wise repetition is not identical to the broadcast. However, if you were to use the `axis` keyword properly, you could in fact get the right result:

```
>>> np.repeat(arr.reshape(n, 1, d), d - 1, axis=1)
array([[[1, 2, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 1, 2]],

       [[3, 4, 3, 4],
        [3, 4, 3, 4],
        [3, 4, 3, 4]]])
```

If you wanted to go the other way, and have the data wrapping around shorter rows, you could just re-interpret the dimensions using a combination of `transpose` and `reshape`:

```
>>> np.broadcast_to(arr.reshape(n, 1, d), (n, d - 1, d)).transpose([0, 2, 1]).reshape(n, d - 1, d)
array([[[1, 1, 1, 2],
        [2, 2, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 2, 2]],
       [[3, 3, 3, 4],
        [4, 4, 3, 3],
        [3, 4, 4, 4]]])
```

Here is a walkthrough of the transformation:

```
>>> arr.reshape(n, 1, d)
array([[[1, 2, 1, 2]],
       [[3, 4, 3, 4]]])
>>> np.broadcast_to(_, (n, d - 1, d))
array([[[1, 2, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 1, 2]],
       [[3, 4, 3, 4],
        [3, 4, 3, 4],
        [3, 4, 3, 4]]])
>>> _.transpose(0, 2, 1)
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]],
       [[3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4]]])
>>> _.reshape(n, d - 1, d)
array([[[1, 1, 1, 2],
        [2, 2, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 2, 2]],
       [[3, 3, 3, 4],
        [4, 4, 3, 3],
        [3, 4, 4, 4]]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the constructives exemples. What about the memory consumption of np.repeat(axis=1) compared to np.broadcast ?

Comment: @Imv. Broadcasting does not copy the data of the original array: it just adjusts strides to be zero in a given axis. Repeat definitely does copy the data. The final example I give, with reshape, transpose, reshape does end up copying the data because it's impossible to do the final reshape without it unfortunately.

Comment: So there is now way to reproduce the behavior of `np.repeat` without copying the data ?

Comment: @Imv. I doubt it.

Comment: @lrnv. Think about it this way: your original buffer is `n, d`. You are effectively trying to turn it into an `n, d-1` array that gets repeated `d` times, but you can't do that if `d-1` and `d` are relatively prime. So you have to repeat the data.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: nice explanation! Regarding your preceding comment: that was my suspicion, i.e. why I'm not sure about (practical) memory efficiency - although a `view` should be more efficient in principle. Did you profile memory usage of the different options?

Comment: @MrFuppes. I didn't profile as such, but I did check that a copy was made and the strides are such that the buffer has been filled out.

Answer (score 2):

`np.broadcast_to` gives you an *array-wise* repeat while `np.repeat` gives you an *element-wise* repeat behavior, see the examples in the docs [[1]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) and [[2]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html). To achieve an equal output in this case, you could change reshaping as follows:

```
import numpy as np
n = 100
d = 10
A = np.random.uniform(size=(n,d))

A_bc = np.broadcast_to(A.reshape(n*d, 1), (n*d, d-1)).reshape(n, d-1, d)
A_rp = np.repeat(A, d-1).reshape(n, d-1, d)

np.all(A_rp == A_bc)
# True
```

Note: although `timeit` indicates that the `broadcast_to` option is slightly faster, I'm not sure if it is actually more memory-efficient.

Comment: `broadcast_to` produces a `view`, but the final `reshape` forces a copy, as @Mad's examples show.  That pretty well eliminates any efficiencies, memory or speed.  Almost any reshape after a `broadcast_to` will force a copy, though the use of `d-1` as the new dimension makes it more obvious.