# ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactl

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with shape `(84, 13, 1036800)` and I want to add a 1d array with len `1036800` to it so that the shape becomes `(84, 14, 1036800)`. I've tried to concatenate and the stack options but keep getting this dimension error.

Comment: The new array has to have (84,1,1036800) shape.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.concatenate` but you should broadcast 1d array first, to multiply first axis with 84 times to accomodate shapes.

```py
a = np.random.randn(84, 13, 1036800)
b = np.random.randn(1036800)
print(a.shape, b.shape)
>>>
(84, 13, 1036800) (1036800,)

b_broadcasted = np.broadcast_to(b, [a.shape[0], 1, a.shape[2]])
print(b_broadcasted.shape)
>>>
(84, 1, 1036800)

np.concatenate([a, b_broadcasted], axis=1).shape
>>>
(84, 14, 1036800)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is the result same when using `np.tile()`

Comment: Yes. But the problem is, np.tile replicates the data, so allocates memory. np.broadcast_to does not. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59667367/numpy-difference-between-np-repeat-and-np-broadcast-to